# Unresolved reference: Gson() in Kotlin Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, gson

I implemented the Lib `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'` in my build.gradle (Module) file but after successfully syncing, the Gson() reference can't be resolved. I searched the whole Internet but everyone says you only need the Lib but I already have it implemented and it doesn't solve my problem...

MainActivity.kt
[image]

```
build.gradle

    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}    

android {
    namespace 'com.example.qrcodescannertest'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qrcodescannertest"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }    

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}   

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'    
    }
```

Does anybody know what the error is here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind to past whole `build.gradle` file in the question please?

Comment: Sure, just a sec

Comment: I hope it's correct that way, I haven't used stackoverflow before... sorry

Comment: Is it just a matter of missing the import for Gson in `MainActivity.kt`?

Comment: I also thought about that but when I open the suggestions on the "Gson()" error with Alt+Enter, there is no suggestion for importing anything. 

Is there a way to do it manually?

Comment: Assuming this is a multi-module project, have you checked that you put it in the correct module's build.gradle?, have you tried invalidating cache~restart? or clean~rebuild project?

Comment: Yeah, I just invalidated cache and restarted, I didn't see your comment till now. It worked fortunately! But thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself:

File -> Invalidate caches & restart once. Now the reference Gson() is valid.

Comment: Usually you only need to refresh Gradle when you make changes to it. It's the button near the top right with an elephant logo and a blue arrow covering part of it. The tooltip labels it "Sync Project With Gradle Files".